# Error en el terminal del codigo (C)

Tags: c

Estoy teniendo un problema con un código de C y es que al compilarlo y correrlo, parte del programa en el terminal se queda en negro y no me muestra todo mi programa, por qué puede ser? Son unas 200 líneas, se debe a que es muy largo? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Es exactamente eso, la cantidad de lineas del programa, dependiendo de la terminal que uses, dependiendo de cual sea tendras q configurar algo similar a "number of scrollback rows" en tu terminal